# Lists: Combine each first, second, third elements in a list of sublists

Tags: f#

I'm trying to zip/concatenate each element with each other.

So

```
[ [1;2;3]; [4;5;6]; [7;8;9] ]
```

will be

```
[ [1;4;7]; [2;5;6]; [3;6;9] ]
```

**My first approach was to use zip. But it didn't work**

```
let transpose (lst : 'a list list)  = 

    List.map List.zip lst

printfn "%A" ( transpose (  [[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]]  ) )
```

**Another approach I tried was like this:**

```
// Helper function
let firstColumn (lst : 'a list list): 'a list  =

    List.map List.head lst

// Helper function
let dropFirstColumn (lst : 'a list list): 'a list list  =

    List.map List.tail lst

// Main function
let transpose (lst: 'a list list) = 

    firstColumn(dropFirstColumn(lst))

printfn "%A" (transpose ( [ [1;2;3];[4;5;6] ] ))
```

I'm not sure how to approach this. I think I need to use map, and somehow iterate over each sublist and extract each element. But any help could be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is going in the right direction - your `firstColumn` function correctly produces the first column and your `dropFirstColumn` gives you the data for the remaining rows of your matrix.

All that is missing is that you need to put the two together and call them recursively until the nested lists in your main list become empty. One way to do this (which works, but does not handle incorrect inputs in a very good way) would look like this:

```
let firstColumn (lst : 'a list list): 'a list  =
    List.map List.head lst

let dropFirstColumn (lst : 'a list list): 'a list list  =
    List.map List.tail lst

let rec transpose list = 
  if List.isEmpty (List.head list) then [] else
    firstColumn list ::
    transpose (dropFirstColumn list)
```

The condition in the `if` checks whether the first nested list is empty - assuming they all have the same length, this means that we got to the end of the list and we just return an empty list. If this is not the case, we process the first column using `firstColumn list`, recursively process remaining columns using `transpose (dropFirstColumn list)` and then join the two using `::`.

You could even inline your two helper functions and write just this:

```
let rec transpose list = 
  if List.isEmpty (List.head list) then [] else
    List.map List.head list ::
    transpose (List.map List.tail list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tomas! I haven't learned about recursive functions yet, but I'm gonna study up on that! Much appreciated you took the time